# how can I get "Asp.net Core 1.1" option

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting both option "asp.net core 2.0" & "2.1". Will it possible to get option "asp.net core 1.1"?

[image]

What component needs to install, could someone suggest!

Comment: What is that a picture of?  Can you at least tell us the tool you are using?

Comment: asp.net core web application template under VS 2017, I can choose asp.net core 2.0 or 2.1 option, now I need 1.1 as well?

Comment: You'll need to install the [.NET Core 1.1 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/1.1) on your machine.

Comment: Ok,  Kirk Larkin, Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, you really shouldn't be creating a *new* ASP.NET Core 1.1 project at this point, anyways. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **Visual Studio Installer** on your machine (and make sure it is up to date) and then select the **Modify** option under the **More** menu.

[image]

Select the **.NET Core cross-platform development** and then in the sidebar, ensure you have checked the **.NET Core 1.0 - 1.1 development tools for Web**. This should download the .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 SDKs for Visual Studio and allow you to use them.

[image]